# Pruning in Alpha Beta: Ordering

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement move ordering in chess to gain the maximum benefit from alpha-beta pruning.

Right now, I'm starting from the root node, expanding it one level, evaluating all of those successors through my evaluation function, sorting them in ascending order (least advantageous to most figuring the answer is somewhere in the middle) and passing the nodes in that order to the alpha-beta algorithm. However, my results are roughly 60% slower than if I just pass the nodes in the order they are on the board. I'm only evaluating from the initial state, but at a high level, is this the correct way that move ordering is implemented?

FWIW, the way I've implemented my move ordering is through the following (maybe the inefficiency is coming how the list is being generated before even being passed to the alpha-beta function?)

```
scores = []
for state in states: 
    scores.append([state,Board(state, player).score()[1]) #this results in a tuple of (board, score)
    scores.sort(key=lambda lst: abs(lst[1]), reverse = False) #sort the list of boards by scores in ascending order
    output = [i[0] for i in scores] #only return the boards, which are then passed to the alpha-beta algorithm
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: I would assume you want to sort the list in descending order, have you tried this?

Comment: Yeah - same result unfortunately.